# Using apaTables or apaStyles packages with knitr

Tags: r, formatting, latex, knitr, reproducible-research

## Problem

Social scientists format tables and documents with [APA style](http://www.apastyle.org/). There are packages like `stargazer` and `xtable` (here is [an extensive list](https://www.r-pkg.org/ctv/ReproducibleResearch)) that provide clean table formatting for those using `latex` and `knitr`. **However**, these packages do not conform to APA style rules in all cases.

Building and formatting tables from scratch is time consuming. Fortunately, there are two R packages for creating tables and documents compliant with APA style guidelines: `apaStyle` and `apaTables`. Unfortunately, **both packages only output to MS Word.**

## Questions

- Is there a way to use `APAStyle` and `APATables` so that output is
  integrated into HTML or PDF output from a .Rmd file?
- What *other* packages do you use to create APA style tables in your .Rmd file—especially when using `knitr` to create PDF files.

Comment: The `tables` package is pretty flexible.  I don't know APA style so I don't know if it outputs that format by default, but it should be possible to get it with enough work.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your second question, check out `apa_table()` from Frederik Aust's package `papaja`. I found it incredibly helpful for reporting all output in APA style (not only tables).

- These [installation instructions and user guide](https://github.com/crsh/papaja) helped me to get started.
- However, to see how much you can actually do with `papaja`, I greatly benefitted from this [openly accessible example paper](https://github.com/methexp/subliminal-EC).

Comment: A list of papers written with `papaja` including more example R Markdown files is available at https://github.com/crsh/papaja#papers-written-with-papaja